# Making Git log stats have their own column?

Tags: git, git-log

I'm trying to make a .csv output file which contains information about the history of repositories which can then be manipulated externally with programs like excel or similar. My current command that I am using is:
`git log --pretty=format:"%h%x09%an%x09%ad%x09%s" --author=x --numstat --sparse --cc --date=local folder > test.csv`

Is there any way to get the  numstat outputs in separate columns, at least away from the commit hash code column?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is unsatisfying: no, there is no way to do that.

There is, however, an easy (if a bit slow) workaround.  Any time Git's existing output formats are unsatisfactory, you can:

1. Replace `git log` (including most of its options) with `git rev-list`, excluding any formatting-and-output-selection oriented `git log` options, and adding `HEAD` if you did not list any branch names.  In this case that would produce:

   ```
   git rev-list --author=x --sparse folder HEAD
   ```
2. Read the output of this command.  It contains the hash IDs of each of the commits you would like to inspect.  You may now run one or more commands like:

   ```
   git log --no-walk --pretty=format:... --cc --numstat <hash>
   ```

   and read through their output, transforming the output to the format you prefer.  (You can use `git log -1` rather than `git log --no-walk`, but I prefer `--no-walk` for illustration, at least.)

The only reason to do this one commit at a time, rather than en masse, is that when doing it en masse, a program attempting to parse the output and re-format it to whatever format you like cannot in general distinguish between output directly from `git log` and text stored in a commit message body, since the latter can mimic the former.  If your output is sufficiently controlled—in this case, it probably is: `%s` text will be all on one line, unlike `%b` or `%B`—you can dispense with the separate `git rev-list`, but you still need a program to read the output and convert it to your preferred format.

A simple [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) program probably suffices, so:

```
git log --pretty=format:"%h%x09%an%x09%ad%x09%s" --author=x \
    --numstat --sparse --cc --date=local folder | awk ... > test.csv
```

would likely work.  Writing the simple awk program is an exercise for you, or fodder for a question posted to [awk](/questions/tagged/awk).  (Hint: consider adding a distinguishing first character to the `--pretty=format:` line, since you know that `--numstat` produces a digit as its first output character for each line.)

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'll read up on awk since I'm not very familiar with all this before asking.